# visual basic button, if elseif else

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, button

i just wanna ask the possible codes like,

```
> If 'button1 is clicked' then
> 
> picturebox1.show()
> 
> Else If 'button2 is clicked' then
> 
> picturebox2.show()
> 
> End If
```

^ something like that

is there anyway i can call if the button is clicked and something would happen? (not inside the button1_clicked) i just need it for my homework, i could not think anything else aside from this

i hope someone could answer this please :(
thanks in advance!!

Comment: If the buttons are exclusive you should look at the RadioButton - add a flowlayout panel and add several buttons. Use Appearance property to change round to rect button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy below code and you are done. But make sure you do not have Button_Click events handled in your code.

:) Enjoy

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf MyClickHandler
    AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf MyClickHandler
End Sub

Private Sub MyClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Select Case CType(sender, Button).Name
        Case "Button1"
               picturebox1.show()

        Case "Button2"
               picturebox2.show()

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I could not understand what the OP wants but `not inside the button1_clicked` makes clear they dont want to use the click event which is what you have

Comment: Actually, question is unclear. It seems that asker wants an alternative to default click handlers. Let us wait for more clarification.

Comment: Please explain the scenario. Then i can suggest something

Comment: i have 2 forms. button from form1 should go to form2. (where this case thing should be) hmm so the case is in the form2 but the buttons are from the form1?

Comment: Please explain in detail what you want to do in these two forms

Comment: sorry i accidentally clicked "add comment" lol.  
i have 2 forms. button from form1 should go to form2. (where this case thing should be) hmm so the case is in the form2 but the buttons are from the form1?

Comment: check my second answer to handle events from more than one forms

Answer (score 0):

This answer is if you want to create a single event handler for different controls from different forms. But such code requires good exception handling. Another drawback is problem in debugging errors.

Add below event handler in a module.

```
Public Sub MyClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


    Dim frm As Form = CType(sender, Button).Parent

    Select Case CType(sender, Button).Name
        Case "Button1"

            If frm.Name = "Form1" Then

                CType(frm.Controls.Item("PictureBox1"), PictureBox).Show()

            End If

        Case "Button2"

            If frm.Name = "Form1" Then

                CType(frm.Controls.Item("PictureBox2"), PictureBox).Show()

            End If

    End Select

End Sub
```

Then you can attach handlers as below:-

```
    AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Module1.MyClickHandler
    AddHandler Button2.Click, AddressOf Module1.MyClickHandler
```